# Could someone identify these microorganisms on microscope?

Tags: microscopy

I'm new in this StackExchange forum, so I don't know if this is an appropriate question.

Can someone please help me recognize these micro-organisms on these photo taken with my phone during my biology lesson using microscope.

Location: Kyjovka river (Czech Republic)

Magnification: 200x

[image]

Comment: What's the source of the sample? The resolution isn't good enough for me, but the source would be very important.

Comment: Unfortunately this is my own photo taken on my smartphone, so there is now way I can give you a better photo. Anyways thank you for your reply. I do not really need the exact name of specific species, anything would help me I think.

Comment: Are you asking about the wormy things? These are most likely some type of nematode (identification of nematode species is usually only achievable biochemically). If you mean something smaller in this sample, I doubt we can help you out (microorganisms are not easily or confidently identifiable by eye)